# How can I fill multiple Lists as fast as possible at the same time?

Tags: c#, list, parallel-processing

Can anybody show me on an best practice console application example how to fill multiple (e.g. 10 lists with 5k random numbers) at the same time (parallel with maximal CPU consumption) as fast as possible, and add each list after it is filled with 5k numbers to a queue?

Comment: Filling a queue with 50,000 random numbers in a single thread should be a fairly fast operation, and adding parallelism in the mix is more likely to make it slower than faster.

Answer (score 1):

Let's implement (in thread safe manner) list creation:

```
   using System.Collections.Concurrent;
   using System.Security.Cryptography;
   using System.Threading;

   ... 

   private static List<int> CreateAndFill(int count) {
     // Random is not thread safe; so we have to use local variable
     // when using local variable, we have to provide entropy
     // which we can get from RNGCryptoServiceProvider
     Random random; 

     using (var provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) {
       byte[] seedData = new byte[sizeof(int)];
       provider.GetBytes(seedData);

       random = new Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(seedData, 0));
     }

     List<int> result = new List<int>(count);

     for (int i = result.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
       result.Add(random.Next(100)); //TODO: put required range here

     return result; 
   }
```

Then you can try `Parallel.For`:

```
   ConcurrentQueue<List<int>> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<List<int>>();

   Parallel.For(0, 10, i => queue.Enqueue(CreateAndFill(5000)));
```

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor): *"In .NET Core, the default seed value is produced by the thread-static, pseudo-random number generator, so the previously described limitation does not apply. Different `Random` objects created in close succession produce different sets of random numbers in .NET Core."*